# Python: How to animate color change of node graphs in Python based on certain values

Tags: python, animation, graph, networkx

Could you help me with the Python code for this requirement?

I am building a networkx graph in Python:

I have nodes and edges as follows:

```
0   1
1   2
0   2
1   3
```

And this is the status of nodes per each step:

```
Node1   Node2   Node3   Node4
0       1       2       3
1       2       3       0
2       3       0       1
```

Here is the code for the graph that I have done:

```
pos=nx.spring_layout(g)
plt.figure(figsize=(5,5))
nx.draw_networkx_nodes(g, pos)
nx.draw_networkx_edges(g, pos,width=0.2, node_size=500)
nx.draw_networkx_labels(g, pos, with_lables=False)
plt.axis('off')
```

For each status, the color is different. How can I animate the color change based on the status for each node in the graph?

Thank you.

Comment: Can you elaborate more on what you mean by status and steps?

Comment: There are 4 statuses: Status 0: color red. Status 1: color green. Status 2: color blue. Status 3: color black. For example: node 1 will change the status from 0 to 1 and to 2. I don’t know how to Illustrate the change of status (colors) of nodes.

Answer (score 2):

So if I correctly understood you want to make an animation showing the status of the nodes as colors in each frame (step). You can pass the node statuses as a list of colors to `node_color` argument in `draw` method and in order to update the statuses in each frame you can create a generator and map them to their corresponding color and update it in each call  by calling the `next()` method:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.animation as animation
import matplotlib

matplotlib.use('TkAgg')

H = nx.from_edgelist([(0, 1), (1, 2), (0, 2), (1, 3)])
pos = nx.spring_layout(H, iterations=200)

# here goes your statuses as a list of lists
statuses = [[0, 1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3, 0], [2, 3, 0, 1]]
colors = {0: 'red', 1: 'green', 2: 'blue', 3: 'black'}

# create a generator from your statuses
# which yields the corresponding color map for each new status
def status():
    for s in statuses:
        yield list(map(lambda x: colors[x], s))  # map statuses to their colors

color_map = status()

def draw_next_status(n):
    plt.cla()
    c_map = next(color_map, colors.values())
    nx.draw(H, pos, node_color=c_map, node_size=700, with_labels=True)


ani = animation.FuncAnimation(plt.gcf(), draw_next_status, interval=1000, frames=len(statuses), repeat=False)

plt.show()
```

This will give you:

[image]

If you want to save it as a gif file, replace `plt.show` by `ani.save('anim.gif', writer='imagemagick')`.

Comment: Hi Azim. Thanks a lot for your help. That is helpful. However, I tried to run the code and it said "Stop Iteration" and I cannot get the gif as yours. 

StopIteration                             Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-6aadefd5aa06> in <module>
     34 
     35 # save it as a gif if you want
---> 36 ani.save('graph_statuses.gif', writer='imagemagick')

Comment: Try it with `ani = animation.FuncAnimation(plt.gcf(), draw_next_status ,interval=1000, repeat=False, frames=iter(status()))`.

Comment: StopIteration still happens. It stops before it reaches the last status.

Comment: And if I have more nodes with more statuses (e.g, 1000 nodes with 2000 steps of statuses, what is the best way to illustrate the animation of color change of the nodes?

Comment: You can just handle the `StopIteration` error by raising an `exception`, it works for me. If you want to have more statuses, then you may just expand the list of statuses or store them in a pandas `dataframe`.

Comment: @ainerd also before saving it as gif, remove the lines with `plt.ioff()` and `plt.show()`.

Comment: @ainerd did this answer help?

Comment: hi Azim, can you help me with the code for "handling the StopIteration error by raising an exception"

Comment: @ainerd I just updated the code, check it again please. If you want to save it as a gif file, replace `plt.show` by `ani.save('anim.gif', writer='imagemagick')`.